# Wordpress contact form 7 not working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM‎

Tags: wordpress, dynamics-crm, crm, contact-form-7

We are using contact form 7 in Wordpress. I want the contact form to send data to our New Microsoft Dynamics CRM‎ through json or Api.
So far I got this but it's not working can someone please help me with this.
In functions.php I have inserted this:

```
function leads_integration_wp_cf7( $cf7 ) {
   $url = your_url_goes_here;
   $postparams = your_post_params_goes_here;

   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postparams);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
}
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', 'leads_integration_wp_cf7');
```

and in php file I have added this:

```
<?php
  $txt = json_encode($_REQUEST);
  $myfile = file_put_contents('log.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Like I said it's not working any tip will help thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you haven't actually written any code to use the Dynamics CRM API, without that nothing will happen.

I suggest you start here: [Use the Microsoft Dynamics CRM Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Our plugin (https://www.saintsystems.com/products/gravity-forms-dynamics-crm-add-on/) fully supports integrating with Microsoft Dynamics CRM On-Premises and Dynamics CRM Online. We support versions 2011 and later.